# Package in repositories labelled "local or obsolete" after upgrade from 14.04 to 14.10

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, synaptic

After upgrading to 14.10, the packages `libcairo2` and `libcairo-gobject2` are listed under  **Installed (local or obsolete)** even though these packages are in the Utopic repositories. A large number of packages on my system depend on these two packages so removing them is not an option.

Is there anything I can do to correct this? I'd like to be able to receive any updates that may become available for these packages.

Answer (score 2):

In order to fix the situation I simply removed the two packages using `dpkg` and re-installed using `apt-get install -f`. The commands I used were:

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -r libcairo2 libcairo-gobject2
sudo apt-get install -f
```